# Python DNS server address already in use

Tags: python, dns

I'm doing lab in Malware analysis.
The task is to investigate CVE-2015-7547 glibc vulnerability.

Google already gave [proof of concept code](https://github.com/fjserna/CVE-2015-7547). This code contains client in C and  fake DNS server in python. When I try to run server, it throws exception:

```
turbolab@sandbox:~/Desktop$ sudo python CVE-2015-7547-poc.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "CVE-2015-7547-poc.py", line 176, in <module>
    tcp_thread()
  File "CVE-2015-7547-poc.py", line 101, in tcp_thread
    sock_tcp.bind((IP, 53))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

IP was set to 127.0.0.1.

How to run server and connect client to it?

Comment: Is something already listening on that port? `netstat -an | grep 53` or  `lsof  | grep LISTEN`  or similar should tell you

Comment: `turbolab@sandbox:~/Desktop$ netstat -an | grep 53     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9532     @/tmp/dbus-FBvArc4F2a
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9531     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9253     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8953     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7053`

Comment: So something's already bound to that port, you presumably have a dns resolver running already

Comment: How can I stop it? After restart the same error appears. don't think another instance of the fake server is running.

Comment: try [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/start-stop-restart-bind9-linux-command/)

Comment: Didn't work. Command `service stop network-manager` worked. However client can't connect to fake server: `CVE: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

Comment: `root@xxxx:/tmp# ./CVE-2015-7547-poc.py 
[UDP] Total Data len recv 36
[UDP] Total Data len recv 36
Connected with 127.0.0.1:56037
[TCP] Total Data len recv 38
[TCP] Request1 len recv 36
[UDP] Total Data len recv 36
[UDP] Total Data len recv 36
Connected with 127.0.0.1:56038
[TCP] Total Data len recv 38
[TCP] Request1 len recv 36`

`root@xxxx:/tmp# ./CVE-2015-7547-client 
CVE-2015-7547-client: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

Interesting, i guess that means its not vulnerable? A vulnerable system segfaults.

Comment: If the POC py is not running, it gives root@xxxx:/tmp# ./CVE-2015-7547-client 
CVE-2015-7547-client: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run `netstat -lpn` to list all listening connections, with pids (-n do not resolve names).

To test for this vulnerability

- Clone the POC code `git clone https://github.com/fjserna/CVE-2015-7547.git`
- Set your DNS server to localhost (127.0.0.1) `edit /etc/resolv.conf`
- Run the POC DNS server
  `sudo python CVE-2015-7547-poc.py`
- Compile the client
  `make`
- Run the client 
  `./CVE-2015-7547-client`

`CVE-2015-7547-client` segfaults when you are vulnerable

`CVE-2015-7547-client` reports `CVE-2015-7547-client: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` when not vulnerable.

See this [Ubuntu Security Notice](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2900-1/) for more information, as well the original [Google blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html)